# C function speed optimalizations for huge cycles

Tags: c, performance, encryption

I'm playing around with [pedagogical implementation](http://www.scard.org/gsm/a51.html) of A5/1 but I suffer from terrible performance of few functions:

```
#define R1MASK      0x07FFFF
#define R1TAPS      0x072000

bit parity(word x) { // XOR all bits
  x ^= x>>16;
  x ^= x>>8;
  x ^= x>>4;
  x ^= x>>2;
  x ^= x>>1;
  return x&1;
}

word clockone(word reg, word mask, word taps) { // clock one register
  word t = reg & taps;
  reg = (reg << 1) & mask;
  reg |= parity(t);
  return reg;
}

bit frameR1bit(word frame, int t) // Compute value of hat{f}_t^reg for chosen frame, chosen register, chosen many times
{
  bit framebit;
  R3 = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
    clockone(R3, R3MASK, R3TAPS); /* clock with frame */
    framebit = (frame >> i) & 1; /* The i-th bit of the frame  */
    R3 ^= framebit;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    clockone(R3, R3MASK, R3TAPS); /* clock */
  return (parity(R3)); // Compute hat{f}_t^reg
}
```

Parameter t is between 79 and 94, frame is 228 bits in array, R3 is word (content of R3 register), everything I can precomputate I have loaded in memory.
The issue is a huge amount of computations of these function. I use function **frameR1bit** in many cycles, so it is computated 2^16 * 512 * 40 * 12 times. The whole program is really slow and I found out it is due to this cycle of **frameR1bit** functions. Does anyone know how to implement this functions better? I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Did you turn optimization on? This could possibly be all inlined.

Comment: as has already been mentioned : try `-Ofast`

Comment: what is `t`? any value from `0..15`? What are any of the params? is `reg` and `t` fixed for example? Or at least if they don't change much then you can pre-calculate all 65536 possible outputs for differing `frame` values.

Comment: -0fast was effective, but not enough.  I got more functions in the cycle, but the speed is still 10-times worse with this function than without. It is about 40 frame iterations per second. There are 2^16 frames.

Comment: You probably should have `R3 = clockone(R3, R3MASK, R3TAPS);` in both places, otherwise the call to `clockone()` doesn't do anything and is likely removed by the optimizer.

Comment: Even if R3 is global variable? Or should I pass reference to R3 as a parameter?

Comment: @Majzlik: Right now it is passed by value so you would have to do `R3 = ...`. Look at your referenced code in the `clock()` and `clockallthree()` functions. You could also pass `R3` as a pointer if you so wished.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it would not be nearly as clear, moving the content of `clockone` and `parity` into your `frameR1bit` function within that loop will buy you back some cycle.  As it stands it is setting and tearing down `t` stack frames for `parity` and `clockone`.  It won't be the biggest savings, but at the machine level that would eliminate more than 16 instructions in each iterations.

This could be accomplished by using `-finline-functions` can do this for you automatically without modifying your code.

Comment: speculating about specific instruction-usage of unknown platforms, toolchains and hardware is extremely likely to produce absolutely wrong statements in every aspect. In fact trying to optimize something like that _may_ produce an even _worse_ performance. This is not 1990 anymore, computer processors already do a lot of optimization themself - in hardware.

Comment: That's what inlining would do. Without effort manual intervention and making it unreadable.